# What is a Rotatable Number™?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

<sub>This is in the spirit of the What is a Word/Phrase™ series started by JLee with a special brand of Phrase™ and Word™ puzzles.</sub>

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it a Rotatable Number.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| ROTATABLE NUMBERS™ | NON-ROTATABLE NUMBERS™ |
| --- | --- |
| 26 | 25 |
| 52 | 46 |
| 78 | 66 |
| 104 | 98 |
| 130 | 137 |
| 156 | 172 |
| 182 | 180 |

If needed, a CSV version is available below.

```
ROTATABLE NUMBERS™,NON-ROTATABLE NUMBERS™
26,25
52,46
78,66
104,98
130,137
156,172
182,180
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted. It seems like a good puzzle. Why the downvotes?

Comment: @clickbait i think it's because they can't accept until 5 min later and then they never came back and accepted.

Answer (score 9):

They're

> multiples of 26, meaning under the ROT-$n$ cipher, any text will stay the same.

Comment: I noticed the pattern, but I think you've got the correct reason

Comment: Correct, But I can't accept it until 5 minutes later.

Comment: It's very well past 5 minutes.

Comment: It's been 4 months.

Comment: ... 15 months later ...

Comment: I think this person forgot or something

Answer (score 7):

Quick Answer

They are

> A multiple of 26

And they are called rotatable because

> I have no idea

Comment: Because you can rotate the alphabet modulo 26?